# Remove URLs and Images from FeedParser

Tags: python, open-source, feed, google-code

I am using http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/ to write a simple news integrator.

But I want pure text ( with `<p>` tags), but no urls or images (ie. no `<a>` or `<img>` tags).

Here are two methods to do that:

1.Edit the source code. http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/source/browse/branches/f8dy/feedparser/feedparser.py

```
class _HTMLSanitizer(_BaseHTMLProcessor):
    acceptable_elements =[....]
```

Simply remove the a & img tags.

2.

```
import feedparser 
feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements = feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements.remove('a')
feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements = feedparser._HTMLSanitizer.acceptable_elements.remove('img')
```

When I use feedparser, first remove the two tags.

Which method is better?

Are there any other good methods?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually, the quicker is better, and this can be determined using python's [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html). But in your case, I'd prefer not to alter the source code but stick with the second option. It helps maintainability.

Other options include writing a custom parser (use a C extension for maximum speed) or just let your site's templating engine (Django maybe?) strip those tags. Well, I' ve changed my mind, the last solution seems the best all-around...